# haskell - Specifying # of conditions that are true

Tags: list, haskell, boolean, conditional-statements

if I have 4 boolean conditions, and I want to say if at least 3 of these are true, then do *_*_, is this possible to implement in Haskell?

Or would I have to go through each permutation? (ie, 1.True, 2.True, 3.True, 4.False and 1.False, 2.True, 3.True, 4.True. etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
atleast :: Int -> [Bool] -> Bool
atleast n bools = length tn == n
  where  tn = take n . filter id $ bools
```

should work lazily unless I missed something.

Answer (score 4):

Each permutation? Of course not.. you can count the number of conditions which are true.

Comment: Yeah, when you get to 3 you can stop counting.

Answer (score 4):

This solution differs from the others provided so far in that it short circuits (ie, stops after finding `n` `Bool`s). So it can operate on some infinite lists (only those that would eventually evaluate to `True`), and won't necessarily force the evaluation of every element in the list (due to laziness).

```
atLeast :: Int -> [Bool] -> Bool
atLeast 0 _          = True
atLeast _ []         = False
atLeast n (True:bs)  = atLeast (n - 1) bs
atLeast n (False:bs) = atLeast n bs
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want it to stop examining the list when you have found N numbers you can count with lazy natural numbers.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Number.Natural

atLeast :: Int -> [Bool] -> Bool
atLeast n = (>= (fromIntegral n :: Natural)) . genericLength . filter id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
atLeast3 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool
atLeast3 b1 b2 b3 b4 = sum (map fromEnum [b1, b2, b3, b4]) >= 3
```

Comment: Maybe not a problem in this case, but what if the list `[b1,b2...bn]` is very large, is there a lazy way of comparing that doesn't need to go through the whole list?

Comment: @MagnusKronqvist, yes, see bisserlis, augustss or solrize's answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most beautiful way, but you might find

```
atLeast :: Int -> [Bool] -> Bool
atLeast n bools = length (filter (==True) bools) >= n
```

easiest to understand. `filter` only keeps the things from your list that satisfy the rule you give it. In this case, the rule is that the answer has to be `True`. Next, `length` counts how many are left.

(A rule is a function `a -> Bool` where `a` is the type of element in your list).

Comment: Yes, like I say, not the most beautiful way, but perhaps easy to understand. I already upvoted Ptharien's Flame for that very point; please consider doing so too.

Comment: This is actually the only place where I find writing `==True` defensible, so I won't argue with you.

Answer (score 1):

```
requireAtLeast :: Int -> [Bool] -> Bool
requireAtLeast n = (>= n) . length . filter id
```

If you prefer extreme pointful or pointless forms, these are them, respectively:

```
requireAtLeast threshold predicates = length (filter (\predicate -> predicate) predicates) >= threshold

requireAtLeast = (. length . filter id) . (<=)
```

Comment: Love the use of `filter id`. `(filter (\predicate -> predicate) predicates)` made me chuckle.